# Help with two very simple but opaque gobbets of neo-Latin

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ecclesiastical-latin, neo-latin

I write again asking for help with two passages of Lawrence of Brindisi.

> 1. Christus autem virga est divinae virtutis : [examples of biblical
>    virgae]. Sed virga ista facta est diversorum colorum, albi et nigri:
>    albedo habitus ac positio est sicut lux, nigredo vero privatio sicut
>    tenebrae.

It's the last bit that I find a bit confusing, on two levels. First, the syntax: "the whiteness is *habitus* and *positio*, like light, while the blackness is privation, like shadows." Is that how this should be understood?

The next question is the sense of *positio*. Obviously derived from *ponere*. But in this religious context, is just plain 'position' appropriate?

> 2. *Quod autem de proximo faciendum est, habendum est pro facto, hinc oriente aurora dicimus factum diem*

For context, here is the surrounding text:

[image]
[image]

Does *de proximo* mean simply "next"? I think that's the logic: 'what must be done next, must be considered as done, hence, at the first light of dawn, we say that it is daytime.'

Comment: Interesting question. 1) Could you provide a source? 2) Re: the first passage, I think _habitus ac positio_ is part of the subject. The way in which the whiteness is set [in this sprout] _is_ like light

Comment: Re: _de proximo_, I think I need more context. It could be referring to a _neighbor_ in the Christian sense: love thy neighbor = dilige proximum tuum. Hence _what has to be done about the neighbor_, etc.

Comment: I don't quite follow your interpretation of the first passage: wouldn't we expect the words to then be in an oblique case (e.g. accusative of respect)?

Comment: Context for the second: https://imgur.com/a/KmYkhE2

Comment: @omniamutantur1 they could be in apposition, though I'm not sure such an apposition would be grammatical. Now that I re-read, I think your reading is more reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your **first question:**

- You understand the syntax correctly.
- *habitus ac positiō* is the 2-for-1 translation equivalent of the single Aristotelian *ἕξις héxis.* A lucid explanation for why this is needed is found in [Bydén (2022)](https://brill.com/view/book/9789004506114/BP000011.xml?language=en):

  > *“Héxis”* is the action noun of the verb *“échein.”* But *“échein”* can be used both transitively, so as to mean “to have – or hold, or contain – (something),” and intransitively, usually with an adverbial modifier, so as to mean “to be (somehow) disposed.” And *“héxis”* is the action noun of both transitive and intransitive *“échein.”* As a result, it is radically ambiguous.

  In English, an equivalent is even harder to find, something like “a having-of/state/disposition.”
- This is opposed to *prīvātiō,* this time a one-word correspondence to the Aristotelian *στέρησις stérēsis,* and to the English “privation.”
- The light-shadow analogy is also straight from A's *On the Soul.*

For your **second question,** the context unambiguously fixes the interpretation of *dē proximō* as a single time adjunct (an adverbial) meaning “very soon, next thing” - such use of *dē* became common already in late Latin (*dē subitō* etc.). In fact [it appears](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/de%20proximo) in DuCange, glossed as “Brevi, intra proximos dies, Gall. Dans peu.”

**Bib:**

- [Bydén, B. (2022).](https://brill.com/view/book/9789004506114/BP000011.xml?language=en) "Chapter 1 Aristotle’s Light Analogy in the Greek Tradition". In *Forms of Representation in the Aristotelian Tradition*

Comment: Thank you very much for this extremely informative response.

Comment: @omniamutantur1 My pleasure - and thank you for the interesting question! I happened to be reading a bit of Aristotle lately (in Russian and Latin rather than Greek) but hadn't reached these concepts yet, so they were also new for me, as is most of ancient philosophy in general. I doubt I would have come across that article otherwise, and it looks like it might be very helpful to me down the line. —(If you think my answer fully covers your question, please consider accepting it and ticking my mental box :D)

Answer (score 7):

Given the context, I'd take the second passage to mean: "that which is to be done shortly/soon/next, should be considered as having been already done".

The thrust of the paragraph is something like: "If Christ has just been born, how can there already be glory and victory? How can there be a harvest when only the seed has yet been born? But that which we know will inevitably happen soon can be taken as a fact, just as when the sun is just rising, we say it's already day." The paragraph gives various analogies between Christ and a seed/the sunrise/etc. as harbingers of something bigger to come, and the sentence you highlight describes the logic behind those analogies.

Admittedly I haven't found a clear parallel for *de proximo* meaning "shortly, soon" or "next", though *proxime* sometimes has that meaning ([L&S, II.B.2.a](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpropior)), so it's only the context that can argue for this reading. Maybe this is a medieval usage (though it doesn't seem to be in [du Cange](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/proximus)).

Comment: Thank you very much—I am glad to see that this generally aligns with how I had read the passage.